# Launch Mongodb in AWS envirement after installation

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

During 3 days I have been trying to install mongo BD in AWS ec2 instance, today finally managed to install it in Ubuntu, now I can't launch it in AWS environment, after numerous  attempts to check the status in aws environment terminal I get errors:

What I have already tried do:

1. installed mongodb on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)
2. launch mongo as a service (Ubuntu)

```
sudo service mongod start
sudo service mongod status
```

3. Go to AWS environment and do attempts to check if I'm connected to DB, and get errors:

> ```
> sudo: mongod: command not found
> mongod: unrecognized service
> sudo: apt-get: command not found
> bash: mongo: command not found
> ```

Please help to set my environment

Comment: Can you clarified what do you mean by "managed to install it in Ubuntu"? Install where? On AWS you just lunch them. And any reason you chose the old ubuntu 16.04, instead of newer ones?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community! Couldn't notice myself that formatting is pretty nice for a new user, seems you have read this already (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I upvote @Marcin suggestion, with what OS you have been operating at your AWS instance? I am 99% sure that it's not `ubuntu`  Could you show us `cat /etc/os-release` command result or relative to it? Isn't EC2 instances configured with `Amazon Linux` by default? (https://aws.amazon.com/mp/linux/)

Comment: @Marcin, I "managed to install it in Ubuntu" because I couldn't install during 3 or 4 days, I choosed  ubuntu 16.04 because I found manual to install mongo https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/, but it suggests only 2 versions of Ubuntu(16 and 14) to create a list file for MongoDB. This is my first experience with DB installation, maybe im doing something wrong..

Comment: @AlexZeDim, thank you for welcoming, I have been operating on Ubuntu, because found more tutorials, honestly I dont understand what is the difference between Amazon Linux and Ubuntu my OS is windows, thats why I also had to use PuTTYgen and its terminal

Comment: @ШоираТашпулатова PuTTY is fine, by the way I am just curious, why are you trying to use EC2 instead of MongoDB Atlas? (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/cluster-tier/) If you need location based your other app from AWS, you could deploy in on Amazon servers, anywhere in the globe.

Comment: @ШоираТашпулатова you might wanna check my answer below. Where you could understand with what version of the OS you are dealing with and find a correct instruction for your operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that Шоира is dealing not with Ubuntu OS but Amazon Linux or so.

So, if she is dealing with Community Edition version of it, the actual docs for every `*nix` based OS can be found [here (MongoDB Docs)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-on-linux/)

And if I remember this fact correctly, AWS instances comes with Amazon Linux by default, so the documentation guide should been read for [Amazon Linux (here)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/), not Ubuntu.

To ensure that she is using Amazon Linus, she must type command `grep ^NAME  /etc/*release` in terminal. If so, the reply should be: `Amazon Linux or Amazon Linux AMI`

Also, I don't know does it matter or not, but [MongoDB Atlas provides also free-tier](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/deploy-free-tier-cluster/) (as EC2 instance) servers in (almost) every data centers from GCP / Azure / AWS, so sometimes it's better to dealing with Cloud Service (which includes Compass and Realms by default, out of the box) instead of using the Community edition of the -raw DB, and write code and https API for it, later.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-50-228:~$ grep ^NAME  /etc/*release
/etc/os-release:NAME="Ubuntu   <<<---but when I check my envirement console I get --->>> ec2-user:~ $ grep ^NAME  /etc/*release
/etc/os-release:NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"

Comment: does that mean that I installed Mongo in Ubuntu, but from the environment console im trying to get access  in Amazon Linux AMI?

Comment: so solution would be installing in Amazon Linux?

Comment: Yea, you right. You are dealing with Amazon Linux, just follow the instructions for it. Don't forget to unwind any of your changes (better to reset the instance, just to be sure) and if my answer will help, don't forget to mark question as solved by accepting it as answer.

Comment: thank you, I managed to install and set mongo DB using aws environment terminal

Answer (score 1):

I tried to **recreate the issue** on an EC2 instance with Ubuntu 16.04:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

I followed the instructions from your link:

- [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

I had **no issues** and was able to install mangoDB as described in the link. The mongoDB is working fine on my instance:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-07-19 08:21:41 UTC; 8s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 3214 (mongod)
    Tasks: 24
   Memory: 69.6M
      CPU: 746ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─3214 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Thus, please double check and ensure that you follow the instructions from the link. **The instructions are correct**.

Also please make sure to use **Ubuntu 16.04**:

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned above, 99% sure that user is dealing not with Ubuntu, but other `unix`-based OS.

Comment: @AlexZeDim The point is that instructions from the link are correct. But I can also add a note about ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, I never doubt in that. Mongo docs are quite right, I am using it myself on my VPS with Ubuntu 20.04 (ba-dum-tss) too.

Comment: I also had no issues  to install mangoDB, it is working fine, \but when I go to AWS environment I cannot get access to my db, from the terminal

Comment: @ШоираТашпулатова Cloud you clarify, what do you mean. To use mongo, you just execute `mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017` as in the instructions from your link. I tested it and it works. I would recommend updating the question with more details, step by step, what are you doing, where and what errors are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

This means that, you are trying to connect to the mongod process running on the local host which is binded on the default port of 27017